# C++: Circular dependency with static members

Tags: c++, class, oop, static, circular-dependency

I have the following code:

```cpp
class B;

class A {
public:
    static int somethingStatic;

    int func() {
        return B::somethingStatic;
    }
};

class B {
public:
    static int somethingStatic;

    int func() {
        return A::somethingStatic;
    }
};
```

Build of that fails, because B is undefined.
So how can I resolve this?

Comment: Put the definition of `A::func` after the definition of `B`. You don't have to write member functions inside the class definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't *define* `A::func()` referencing B's members before at least declaring B. A forward declaration of B is just saying that a class called B will exist, nothing about B's members. You can however *declare* `A::func()`.

One way to do this is the typical .h file / .cpp file combination. If for whatever reason you want all of A and B -- declaration and definition -- in one file it can be done as below:

```
class A {
public:
    static int somethingStatic;

    int func();
};

class B {
public:
    static int somethingStatic;

    int func() {
        return A::somethingStatic;
    }
};

int A::func() {
    return B::somethingStatic;
}

int A::somethingStatic = 42;
int B::somethingStatic = 5;
```

Notice that in this case it is no longer even necessary to forward declare B, as the declaration of A is not dependent on B at all. The same would be true if you broke out the definition of both into a separate .cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

Move *definitions* of member functions out of the class *declaration*:

```
// declarations go into a header file
class A {
public:
    static int somethingStatic;
    int func();
};

class B {
public:
    static int somethingStatic;
    int func();
};

// definitions go into a cpp file
int A::func() {
    return B::somethingStatic;
}

int B::func() {
    return A::somethingStatic;
}

// don't forget to define static member variables:
int A::somethingStatic;
int B::somethingStatic;
```

Separating declarations and definitions should be your "default mode of operation", because removing the implementation from the header makes your code easier to navigate.